# Is there any extension for sockets in c++?

Tags: c++, sockets

I know to use sockets in C. 
But, is there any more comfortable/different way to do that with C++? 
Or when I use sockets in C++, is it the same as using it in C?

Comment: 1) Why should the C PreProcessor support sockets? 2) C is not C++ is not C, so why add the C tag for a C++ question?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: Generally speaking, you can use any C library in a C++ project. There are C++ wrappers for C sockets out there, there is Boost.Asio, and it's next to impossible to tell what you need.

Comment: @Olaf I think, CPP means just C plus plus = C++, not the pre-processor. And for the question itself: There is no standard in C++ (yet), but there are libraries like Boost that offer TCP/IP and socket functionality with a higher abstraction.

Comment: @Rene: Maybe you read my comment carefully again. And I did not ask that question.

Comment: @Olaf Re-reading your comment still leads me to the conclusion that you misinterpreted the CPP in the original post, before the edit. After the edit of the OP it is very clear: He asks about C++. And the second part of my comment was the answer to the question of the OP, not directed to you anymore. (Cannot add newlines in comments, maybe should have made it two comments).

Answer (score 3):

Use Boost.Asio for sockets in C++.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: Why please? because its faster? more comfortable? or what? (and thanks for the answer.)

Comment: @naivemango: You asked for "more comfortable / different". If you want a better tailored answer, improve the question to include your requirements. Boost is generally considered the "standard" library to look at when the standard library does not give you what you need.

Comment: @naivemango It's a non-blocking input output library. You can use it for sockets to save you a lot of work. Non-blocking means the program won't hang when accepting connections and receiving data. And you just asked for something else. You can look more into it.

Comment: @naivemango it might be more comfortable, buy it depends on you. Faster, maybe, maybe not. I usually cannot reliably read Boost's source but I expect this library uses normal C sockets deep down at its core. Ultimately, as previously said, you only asked for an alternative, not it's specifics. Boost.Asio is not the only one. You also have the POCO C++, ACE and many other socket libraries. Use Google to compare them. It helps a lot.